# Blank screen on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am using Anaconda navigator Jupyter notebook in Window10 environment. After sometime when I start my Jupyter notebook, it starting displaying a blank screen with no active buttons/tabs, without any error and my existing old code. The similar problem shared on the internet some error message is displaying, I am getting no error or any description. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: What does it show on the terminal that you start Jupyter notebook?

Comment: it shows no information or error. Only web page of jupyter notebook gets unresponsive. Is there any specific way to check terminal?